# Why does loop statement have uneven number of binding vectors?

Tags: clojure

I've been looking at examples and documentation; and I cannot figure out why I'm getting the

`loop requires an even number of forms in binding vector` error.

I believe the problem is in the loop and initializing usage-indicies. I just cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
(def usage-vec-len 13)

(defn ret-usage-indicies
"Takes a billed water consumption amount, and returns a vector of the ranges."
[reading]
(let [usage-indicies [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] curr-idx (- usage-vec-len 1)]
 (loop [curr-reading reading ui usage-indicies curr-idx]
.
.
.
 (if (= remaining-reading 0)
 ui
 (recur remaining-reading (assoc ui curr-idx curr-reading) (dec curr-idx)))))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `loop` form should look just like a `let` form. You can add comma whitespace for clarity:

```
(loop [symbol1 init1, symbol2 init2, ...] body-of-expressions)
```

It looks like you might want

```
(loop [curr-reading reading, ui usage-indicies, curr-idx curr-idx] ...)
```

where `curr-index` is initialized (rebound) to `curr-index` from the `let` expression.

Better, you could move the initialization you having going on in your `let` form down to the `loop` form itself. It also looks as if `usage-vec-len` is just the `count` of `usage-indices`, so no need to specify that in a global `def` when you can take care of that in the loop binding as well.

```
(loop [curr-reading reading
       ui [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
       curr-idx (dec (count ui))] 
   body-of-expressions)
```

Comment: Thank you. Silly me. I see it in your example.